# Error App crashes when data is Fetching firebase database in recycler view by model class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I generated signed apk and test it app crash where data is Fetching from firebase in recycler view.
But when I install debug apk from android studio then no crash appear

Comment: are you using proguard !

Comment: Yes it is automatically add when we generate signed apk

Comment: you actually can enable and disable the proguard , i guess it is proguard that is causing your app to crrash , try to disable proguard and generate a signed apk and see if it works

Comment: There are a bunch of possible reasons, so I recommend searching for the error message: https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+No+properties+to+serialize+found+on+class If you're having a hard time applying those to your case, or think your case is different then any of those, edit your question to show the [minimal code/configuration that are needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).